# Creating a row number column based on another columns value

Tags: sql, row-number

I have the following data:
[image]

it's a calendar that has date and year/week number there week is our internal calendar. what i want to do is sort by the most recent week number and have that be `rel_week_index=1`, and then the previous week be `rel_week_index=2`, etc. I got this to work by doing `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY YEAR ORDER BY YEAR DESC)`, however, once you get to the previous year, this `rel_week_index` column starts over at 1, which isn't what i want.

Ideally `year_week=202111` would be `rel_week_index=1`, `year_week=202110` would be `rel_week_index=2` and so on.

Comment: That's like asking: "How to say 'sorry' in that European language?" But you're not going to tell which one. What's your RDBMS and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this is the query to calculate row number based on year and week combination in descending order:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY YEAR_week DESC)
```

Comment: Please let me know if there is any more difficulties with this query.